# Как заставить картинку двигаться за filled в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как сделать что бы леденец двигался в месте с полоской загрузки Все сделано из image, перерыл весь интернет, так и не нашел решение.

Comment: координаты в Update ему пересчитывайте

Comment: Положение прогресс бара это не тайна! Как абсолютное, так и относительное, известны положение лейаута, размеры, якорь, вот прям ваще ВСЁ!